# Size the page content to the viewport in google page speed

Tags: html, google-pagespeed

I am testing my site https://www.industrialstores.com/ in google page speed but user experience under mobile tab, it is showing to correct this "The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience."

I set my viewport in header as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I tried different viewports defined in different stackoverflow question but not able to find my solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Check out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: I already added the viewport as you mentioned but still getting the same message in pagepseed